# Lightning: How to make related records read-only on page layouts?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lookup, page-layout, read-only

I have added a Contact lookup to Account, and I am displaying it on the Account layout via the Related Record component. But I don't want to define a Create Action for it. In other words I want the Related Record component to be in read-only mode.

Is there a way?

Comment: You should remove the create ability from the profile and sharing settings

Comment: @ItaiShmida I don't want to block users from creating Contacts altogether; I only want to block record create from the Related Record component.

Comment: So as far as I know - this is impossible to do in lightning

Answer (score 1):

One workaround I was able to employ is setting all fields as read-only on the compact layout for the update and/or create action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the New button from the list view on the page layout. Under Setup>Object Manger>Account>PageLayouts>edit then click the wrench on the list you want 'read-only' and expend the buttons section. Uncheck the button New

Comment: Thank you. You are talking about related lists in page layouts while this question is about the Related Record component in Lightning pages.

Comment: Ah Gotcha - my apologies.